# Genitiv nach "entledigen"

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

Ich habe gerade in der deutschen Übersetzung von The Remains of the Day (zu Deutsch: Was vom Tage übrigblieb) folgenden Satz gelesen:

> "Aber ich muss gestehen, dass dieser scherzhafte Umgangston zu den Pflichten gehört, deren ich mich niemals mit Begeisterung entledigen könnte".

Auf "entledigen" folgt ja normalerweise der Genitiv, also hier theoretisch (?) "derer", denn die "Pflichten" sind ja weiblich. Es würde mich also interessieren, warum hier der männliche Genitiv Plural benutzt wird (ich gehe einfach davon aus, dass bei der Übersetzung eines Literaturnobelpreis-Werkes keine Grammatikfehler unterlaufen sind).

Comment: "deren" bezieht sich auf die "Pflichten", die ihrerseits im Plural stehen.

Answer (score 2):

Es sieht so aus als wären beide Formen möglich, wenn das Relativpronomen zu einem Verb gehört (entledigen):

https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/deren-derer

Ich persönlich hätte aber auch nach kurzer Kontemplation "deren" gewählt, ganz einfach weil ich mich fragen würde

> "Wessen wollte er sich nicht entledigen ?".

Auch:

> "Auch das gehört zu den Pflichten, unter ihnen die der Einhaltung der Kehrwoche, deren er sich gerne ..."